# Execution failed for task :app:mergeReleaseResources

Tags: java, android

this is my build.gradle file:

```
`apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`

`android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.****.erp'
        minSdkVersion 15
    // targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
     }
    }
    productFlavors {
 }
 namespace 'com.****.erp'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
      exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
 testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

}
android{
  aaptOptions.cruncherEnabled = false
    aaptOptions.useNewCruncher = false
}
```

`

when I want to build I got this error message:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong:
> Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable
> Resource compilation failed (Failed to compile values resource file C:\Users\majid-pc\Documents\Prj\ERP\app\build\intermediates\incremental\release\mergeReleaseResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml. Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@6b387bc3.). Check logs for more details.

my android studio version:

> Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 2
> Build #AI-223.8836.35.2231.10811636, built on September 15, 2023
> Runtime version: 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-10027231 amd64
> VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
> Windows 10 10.0
> GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
> Memory: 2048M
> Cores: 4
> Registry:
> external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
> ide.text.editor.with.preview.show.floating.toolbar=false
> ide.instant.shutdown=false

It should builds my apk.

.caches resource:

> C:\Users\majid-pc.gradle\caches\transforms-3\56e5e0dd128196c308e382e8342f0793\transformed\appcompat-v7-28.0.0\res\values\values.xml:1404:4:
>  inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.

Comment: There is something wrong with values.xml, check its content or recent changes. Also cleaning often solves problems.